# Zebra stripping not working in IE8

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, zebra-striping

I wrote the following jquery to apply zebra stripping to a certain row in a table. This works fine in Chrome and Firefox but doesnt work in IE8. W

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("tr.alt:even").css("background-color", "#f0f8ff");
$("tr.alt:odd").css("background-color", "#fcfceb");
});
</script>
```

Here is the HTML

```
<tr class="alt">
    <td class="status"></td>
    <td class>Received</td>
</tr>
<tr class="alt">
    <td class="status"></td>
    <td class>Received</td>
</tr>
<tr class="alt">
    <td class="status"></td>
    <td class>Received</td>
</tr>
<tr class="alt">
    <td class="status></td>
    <td class>Received</td>
</tr>
<tr class="alt">
    <td class="status></td>
    <td class>Received</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Can I suggest doing this in just pure CSS? With maybe a polyfill for the older IE browsers?

Comment: How would i do this with CSS...?? I do not know how many rows i'll be getting from the database

Comment: pretty similar to js... `tr.alt:nth-child(odd){background:red;}` - you will need to polyfill for IE8 and below though.

Comment: Your code should work. Make sure that the surrounding html is valid.

Comment: I made sure and still doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<style type="text/css">
  tr.odd 
{
    background:fcfceb;
}   
  tr.even 
{
    background:f0f8ff;
}
tr.zero 
{
    background-color:#FFE4E1;
}
</style>

<script>
  jQuery(function($) {
    $("tr.alternateColor:odd").addClass("odd");
    $("tr.alternateColor:even").addClass("even");
</script>
```

Finally got it to run. I was having issues with my CSS in IE

Answer (score 3):

(tested in IE 7,8...)
Fix your markup and it will work flawlessly: `class="status` <- missing `"`
`<td class>`  = invalid attr

```
<table>
<tr class="alt">
    <td class="status"></td>
    <td>Received</td>
</tr>
<tr class="alt">
    <td class="status"></td>
    <td>Received</td>
</tr>
<tr class="alt">
    <td class="status"></td>
    <td>Received</td>
</tr>
<tr class="alt">
    <td class="status"></td>
    <td>Received</td>
</tr>
<tr class="alt">
    <td class="status"></td>
    <td>Received</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Or it should be:

```
<table>
<tr class="alt">
    <td class="status"></td>
    <td class="Received"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="alt">
    <td class="status"></td>
    <td class="Received"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="alt">
    <td class="status"></td>
    <td class="Received"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="alt">
    <td class="status"></td>
    <td class="Received"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="alt">
    <td class="status"></td>
    <td class="Received"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I don't know, both works, pick your choice

Comment: Do i need to have a certain security level or something on my browser

Comment: No. http://webdesign.about.com/od/css3/qt/alternating-row-styles-tables.htm check this article on how to do it with pure CSS

Comment: @roXon *"not working in IE8"* do those css3 selectors work in IE8? using css3 would have the same problem that he currently has.